# Angular 10 | Getting query params in URL null or undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this route with the query param `lang`:

```
http://localhost:4200/?lang=de
```

None of the following examples work, it is always null or undefined

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { 
  console.log(this.route.snapshot.params.lang);
  console.log(this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('lang'));
}

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
    let lang = params['lang'];  
    console.log(lang);
  });
  console.log(this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('lang'));
  console.log(this.route.snapshot.params.lang);
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I have now read several guides, even some for angular 10. Each of them show the above examples, but I still cannot get the value of `lang`.

Comment: What is your version of angular ?

Comment: Did you try checking the Value of de , before passing it as a param

Comment: can you try this this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('lang');

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is my working solution:

```
var url = new URL(window.location.href);
var lang = url.searchParams.get("lang");
```

This works in ngInit and in constructor.

Comment: This also works in app.component without router-outlet!

Comment: This solution isn't correct for SSR.

Answer (score 3):

For the Observable mechanism, you can use paramMap observable like this with an undefined check.

```
this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
if(params.get('lang')){
    let lang = params.get('lang');  
    console.log(lang);
    }
  });
```

And other solutions @Leo has already proposed.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know if this method can be used without using the current route? For example: `this.router.parseUrl('https://myapiendpoint.com?page=2');`

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('lang');
```

From the [official documentation](https://angular.io/guide/router#accessing-query-parameters-and-fragments) ?

Comment: Did you try it in constructor or ngOnInit ?

Comment: I have tried in in constructor, but I found an other solution, see my answer

Comment: Ok, glad you found your answer. I would still try my answer in `ngOnInit` though, as it more the "angular way".

Answer (score 0):

```
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
              private router: Router) {
    this.route.queryParamMap.pipe(
      filter(queryParamMap => queryParamMap.has('lang'))
    ).subscribe(queryParamMap => {
      const lang = queryParamMap.get('lang');
      console.log(lang);
    });

    this.router.events.pipe(
      filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
      switchMapTo(this.route.queryParamMap)
    ).subscribe(queryParamMap => {
      const lang = queryParamMap.get('lang');
      console.log(lang);
    });
  }
```